# flash file does not appear

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a flash file to my frame , it works fine ,but when I make the frame using netbeans , the flash file did not work any more , but when I remove the "initComponent()" method it works, but I do not want to remove this method , why this method make the flash file not working or prevent to add it to the frame ??

this is the code :

```
public class SimpleFlashExample_1 extends JFrame{ 

 public SimpleFlashExample_1() {

   initComponents();

    JFlashPlayer flashPlayer = new JFlashPlayer();
    flashPlayer.load(getClass(), "/clientserver/fl.swf");
    add(flashPlayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 675, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 475, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();
    NativeInterface.open();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
      public void run() {

        new SimpleFlashExample_1().setVisible(true);
    }
   });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();
  }

}
```

Comment: could you please revise and rephrase your question so the question is clearer?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht : I edited the question. hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a few moments to read through the code...

```
public SimpleFlashExample_1() {
    // 1...
    initComponents();
    JFlashPlayer flashPlayer = new JFlashPlayer();
    flashPlayer.load(getClass(), "/clientserver/fl.swf");
    // 3...
    add(flashPlayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private void initComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // 2....
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 675, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 475, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}
```

First, you call `initComponents`.  `initComponents` calls `getContentPane().setLayout(layout);`, assigning a `GroupLayout` as the layout manager for the frame.  You then add your flash player to the frame, trying to use a `BorderLayout` constraint, which isn't going to be compatible with the `GroupLayout` (and is apparently ignored)

Why you component doesn't actually show comes down to any number of factors, I would surmise that the flash player either doesn't have a preferred size or the `GroupLayout`, not knowing what else to do with it, is ignoring the component

Try setting the layout for the frame as `BorderLayout` in the form designer